# (Javascript) How to return two promises in one function on different condition

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, rxjs

I have a function calc(), which may have following:

```
calc() {
    ...
    if (condition) {
        return new Promise(...) ; // promise1
    }
    else {
        return new Promise(...); // promise2
    }
}
```

The function calls it will act on these two promises differently:

```
calc().then()=>{ do something; } // if promise 1;
      .then()=>{ do nothing; } // if promise 2;
```

Is it possible to do?

The reason I am asking is that calc() itself is an asynchronous function. It is subscribing to some process like:

```
calc () {

    subscribe(()=> { do something and need to flash upper caller that is done;}
}
```

so if calc() does not receive signal from another process, it will not yield results, and upper caller does have the necessary data to proceed.

Comment: I will add more color to the question.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimum working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know the result of the condition synchronously. Why not wrap the promises in an object and have a property such as id, to denote which promise was returned?

```
calc() {
    ...
    if (condition) {
        return { id: 1, promise: new Promise(...) }; // promise1
    }
    else {
        return { id: 2, promise: new Promise(...) }; // promise2
    }
}
```

You can then decide what to do with the promises based on the id returned.

```
const result = calc();

if(result.id === 1){
    result.then()=>{ do something; } // if promise 1;
}
else if(result.id === 2) {
    result.then()=>{ do nothing; } // if promise 2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The thing is that, promise 1 is what I want and it might take longer time to generate, but promise 2 is instantly generated. So how should I call calc()?